# How to Define and Use Variables in Pymongo Aggregation Script

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to learn about mongodb aggregation. I've been able to get the commands to work for a single output. I am now working on a pymongo script to parse through a dirty collection and output sterilised data into a clean collection. I am stuck on how to define variables properly so that I can use them in the aggregation command. Please forgive me if this turns out to be a trivial matter. But I've been searching through online documents for a while now, but I've not had any luck.

This is the script so far:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os, glob, json
#
var_Ticker = "corn"
var_Instrument = "Instrument"
var_Date = "Date"
var_OpenPrice = "prices.openPrice.bid"
var_HighPrice = "prices.highPrice.bid"
var_LowPrice = "prices.lowPrice.bid"
var_ClosePrice = "prices.closePrice.bid"
var_Volume = "prices.lastTradedVolume"
var_Unwind = "$prices"
#
#
client = MongoClient()
db = client.cmdty
col_clean = var_Ticker + "_clean"
col_dirty = var_Ticker + "_dirty"
db[col_dirty].aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,var_Instrument:1,var_Date:1,var_OpenPrice:1,var_HighPrice:1,var_LowPrice:1,var_ClosePrice:1,var_Volume:1}},{$unwind:var_Unwind},{$out:col_clean}])
```

This is the error that I get:

```
>>> db[col_dirty].aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,var_Instrument:1,var_Date:1,var_OpenPrice:1,var_HighPrice:1,var_LowPrice:1,var_ClosePrice:1,var_Volume:1}},{$unwind:var_Unwind},{$out:col_clean}])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    db[col_dirty].aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,var_Instrument:1,var_Date:1,var_OpenPrice:1,var_HighPrice:1,var_LowPrice:1,var_ClosePrice:1,var_Volume:1}},{$unwind:var_Unwind},{$out:col_clean}])
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I take out the variables and use the proper values, the command works fine.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you must wrap a literal string like "$project" in quotes:

```
db[col_dirty].aggregate([{"$project":{"_id":0,var_Instrument:1 ...
```

The same goes for "_id", which is a literal string. This is different from how Javascript treats dictionary keys.

Note that you should *not* put quotes around var_Instrument, since that is not a string literal, it's a variable whose value is a string.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Spot on. I implemented this ad it worked perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: How to use `$$some_variable` in python with `pymongo`?